# how to share code between Unobtrusive JavaScript in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unobtrusive-javascript

As the title, I want to abstract some function and share them between different unobtrusive javascript files. How can I do?

To be more specific, for example, I have two files: show.js.erb, create.js.erb in views/object/

When I response to ajax request, I will render them.

Now this two files share some same code, so I want to abstract them and put it to a new file.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with `html.erb` files you can also have partial for `js.erb` files.
Just extract the common code into a partial (starting with a `_`, so e.g `_common_code.js.erb` in `views/object/`).
Then you can just use the render function in the `show.js.erb` or `create.js.erb` files like this to include your common code.

```
render "common_code"
```

Answer (score 0):

try extract common logic to separate file, include it to layout and use common functions from *.js.erb files.